# Continued fractions formula

Tags: continued-fractions

How would I find the continued fraction of and number $a/b$?
For example, $5/8$ = $1/(1+3/5)$
I tried using its decimal expansion but couldn’t find anything, and I want to be able to describe the golden ratio as a fraction.

Comment: ... just continue the process to get the continued fraction expansion of $5/8$, so $5/8=1/(8/5)=1/(1+3/5)=1/(1+1/(5/3))=1/(1+1/(1+2/3))=1/(1+1/(1+1+(3/2)))=1/(1+1/(1+1+(1+1/2)))=[0;1, 1, 1, 2]$. The golden ratio is in this sense using the Fibonacci sequence $[0;1,1,1,1,\dots]$ .

Comment: Thank you so much